# Does $k(\mathbf{u+v}) = k\mathbf{u}+k\mathbf{v}$ apply for complex vectors and scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

I am trying to solve for $\mathbf x$ (a complex vector) in the equation:

$$i\mathbf{x} - 3\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}$$

where $\mathbf{u} = \langle3-4i, 2+i, -6i\rangle$ and $\mathbf{v} = \langle 1+i, 2-i, 4\rangle$.

I did this bit of algebra:
\begin{align}
i\mathbf{x} - 3\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}  &\implies i\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{u} + 3\mathbf{v} \\
&\implies \mathbf{x} = -i(\mathbf{u}+3\mathbf{v}) \\
&\implies \mathbf{x} = -i\mathbf{u} -3i\mathbf{v}
\end{align}

Which gave me $\mathbf{x} = \langle-1-6i, -2-8i, -6-12i\rangle$.

However the solution guide to my textbook says the answer is:

$$\mathbf{x} = \langle 7 − 6i, −4 − 8i, 6 − 12i\rangle$$

It seems the complex components of my answer are the same as those in the solution, and that there's some sort of multiplication by $-1$ happening to the real parts of $\mathbf{u}$ or $\mathbf{v}$. So I'm wondering if there's some kind of subtlety in the properties of complex numbers that I'm missing. Or maybe my algebra is wrong, or maybe I'm just hopelessly confused.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The book is just wrong. It happens. Plugging its answer into the original equation causes a mismatch.

Comment: In regards to the question posed in the title, scalar distribution over vector addition (i.e. $c(\mathbf{v+u}) = c\mathbf{v} + c\mathbf{u}$) is [one of the eight typical axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html) used to define a vector space. This property most certainly holds for "complex vectors" over the complex field.

Comment: I think you are right.
$ix - 3 (1+i, 2-i, 4)
 = (3-4i, 2+i, -6i)\implies ix=(3-4i+3+3i, 2+i+6-3i, -6i+12) .$
So $x=-i(6-i, 8-2i,12-6i)=(-1-6i,-2-8i,-6-12i) $.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  I agree with all the above comments

Comment: Thank you all for your help, glad to see its my textbook that's wrong and not my entire mathematical intuition.

Comment: @FrancoMiranda If you are satisfied with the answers you have received in the comments, consider posting an answer to this question yourself and accepting it so that this question may be removed from the unanswered question tab.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the textbook was wrong and I got the right answer.
thank you to ZeroXLR who reminded me I could just plug x into the original equation to check if it holds.
thank you to Brian who reminded me since the complex vector space is a vector space, all 8 vector space axioms must hold, which includes k(u+v) = ku + kv